# Создание бесплатного аккаунта Oracle

Tags: oracle

Собственно, вопрос тривиальный, но все же беспокоит немного. Хотел для себя опробовать Oracle Data Provider, скачав продукт по данной ссылке http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html. Но нужен бесплатный аккаунт. Рабочий телефон, название компании, адрес - для чего заполнение этих полей? А если человек не хочет раскрывать место работы или вообще фрилансер?

Comment: боюсь на этот вопрос вам могут ответить только в корпорации oracle, а не тут. заполните их левыми данными и не парьтесь

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вопрос в техподдержку компании Oracle.